# How do you find a tangent in a 3D shape?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a three-dimensional shape. I will share an animation of the 3D shape, and refer to it by colorized regions henceforth.

The base is a right-angle triangle - that is static and won't change.
The length of the (vertical) opposite side, yellow, is dynamic and can change.

The variables I have the values of are the tangent angle of red, the tangent angle of green, and the adjacent length of green... How can I solve for the tangent angle of blue?

Figure 1:
https://i.imgur.com/eUzCd5B.mp4

I want to find a way to calculate hip angles on roofs, provided only the adjacent length of the hip (not the hypotenuse) and the theta angles(?) of the slopes that form the hip corner. I have means of performing that, but it is unreliable in some circumstances.

Figure 2:
https://i.imgur.com/VxYzuO3.png

*Edit 1:
My current method is explained in this image. I am attempting to solve for the theta of Z using only the theta and adjacent length of Y, and the theta of C.

For the sake of the problem, let's say C and Z are both tangents of 0.5, and the adjacent length of Y is 25 feet.

*Edit 2: Staring at my hand-drawn model, I noticed something: the relationship between theta of (C) and theta of (Z) is fixed. If I change the length of adjacent (A) [if I increase the size of my imaginary pyramid,) as long as length of opposite (B) is scaled proportionally, theta (C) and (Z) remain fixed, and their relation to each other does not change either.

Even if I only scale (B), while the theta for (C) and (Z) will change, they should change in a manner that is proportional and can be mathematically expressed in relation to each other.

It almost seems like the only variable I should need to solve for theta of (Z) is theta of (C), with a couple fixed points of reference, notably that theta of (Y) will always be 1.0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have edited my OP with further context, including an image I made to explain the problem to a friend I was seeking help from.
Apologies if my terminology and/or explanation are poor.

Comment: Show all the steps of an example where the calculation does not work, using actual numbers. I think that's the only way we'll be able to figure out what's going wrong for you.

Comment: It's not so much what's going wrong, as what I can't figure out. Again, I have a calculation method that works - but that method is lacking in certain scenarios. 
I can't find a formula that will work reliably for, what I would call a "3D" trig problem. 

Do forums like this no longer provide help for general problem-solving? Forgive me if I'm behind the curve.. It's been many years since I frequented a board like this.

Comment: You say you have a formula but we don't know what that is. So It is hard to say how to fix what cannot be seen. It is also not clear to me exactly what angles you are looking for. If you could label some corners that would help.

Comment: @Paul I've updated the post with a bit more context of some common example measurements, and an explanation of the exact problem using the labeled dimensions in my image explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

So I plotted the pitches of the roof, expressed as tangents, in a spreadsheet. As detailed in Figure 2, I used these and fixed adjacent lengths for the calculation of roof height (opposite) and corner (the roof's "hip") length.
I made multiple different identical lines of this calculation, showing the tangents for each. I then subtracted my column of (Z) tangents) from (C) tangents, giving me a new column. Finally, I subtracted each of these from each other, and found a fixed mathematical relation of 0.02 decrease between each of these values.
Upon concluding there was a fixed relation, and looking over my chart, I realized the original question could be boiled down to a simple algebra problem:

**Tangent (C) * X = Tangent (Z).**

**X is 1.315789473684211.**

**If you divide the tangent of the slope (C) by 1.31, assuming you are dealing with a shape that when simplified is effectively a four-sided pyramid, you can find the tangent of a corner (Z).**

Refer to Fig. 2 in OP for an explanation of labels and a visual of relations between variables.